# Why does JavaScript preferentially coerce to strings when concatenating but numbers when comparing?

Tags: javascript, types, equality, coercion

Why does JavaScript preferentially coerce operands to strings when using the concatenate `+` operator but preferentially coerce operands to numbers when performing `==` equality checks?

`'1' + 1` is coerced to `'1' + '1'` and returns `'11'`.

`'1' == 1` is coerced to `1 === 1` and returns `true`.

In the comparison case they are coerced to numbers, and not strings. See sources below:

1) [Douglas Crockford's Encyclopedia](https://www.crockford.com/javascript/encyclopedia/index.html#4D3D%20infix%20operator)

> The == operator produces the same result as this function:

```
function coercing_equal(left, right) {
    if (left === right) {
        return true ;
    }
    if (left === null) {
        return right === undefined;
    }
    if (right === null) {
        return left === undefined;
    }
    if (typeof left === 'number' && typeof right === 'string') {
        return left === +right;
    }
    if (typeof left === 'string' && typeof right === 'number') {
        return +left === right;
    }
    if (typeof left === 'boolean') {
        return coercing_equal(+left, right);
    }
    if (typeof right === 'boolean') {
        return coercing_equal(left, +right);
    }
    if
        (typeof left === 'object' &&
        (
            left.constructor === Number ||
            left.constructor === String ||
            left.constructor === Boolean
        ) &&
        (typeof right === 'string' || typeof right === 'number')
    ) {
        return coercing_equal(left.valueOf(), right);
    }
    if (
        (typeof left === 'string' || typeof left === 'number') &&
        typeof right === 'object' &&
        (
            right.constructor === Number ||
            right.constructor === String ||
            right.constructor === Boolean
        )
    ) {
        return coercing_equal(left, right.valueOf());
    }
    return false ;
}
```

2) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

> When type conversion is involved in the comparison (i.e., non–strict comparison), JavaScript converts the types String, Number, Boolean, or Object operands as follows:
>
> **When comparing a number and a string, the string is converted to a number value. JavaScript attempts to convert the string numeric literal to a Number type value. First, a mathematical value is derived from the string numeric literal. Next, this value is rounded to nearest Number type value.**
>
> If one of the operands is Boolean, the Boolean operand is converted to 1 if it is true and +0 if it is false.
>
> If an object is compared with a number or string, JavaScript attempts to return the default value for the object. Operators attempt to convert the object to a primitive value, a String or Number value, using the valueOf and toString methods of the objects. If this attempt to convert the object fails, a runtime error is generated.
>
> Note that an object is converted into a primitive if, and only if, its comparand is a primitive. If both operands are objects, they're compared as objects, and the equality test is true only if both refer the same object.

Is there any rhyme of reason to this or is it just another case of 'because JavaScript'? It is tough to remember as far as my understanding currently takes me.

Comment: Read the specification.

Comment: `'1' + 1` == `('1').toString() + (1).toString()`

Comment: How do you know `'1' == 1` is coerced to `1 === 1` and not `'1' === '1'`?

Comment: @jhpratt was reading through Crockford's JavaScript encyclopedia (https://www.crockford.com/javascript/encyclopedia/index.html)

Comment: @AdamThompson Can you point to a specific section? That's a massive document.

Comment: @jhpratt the "== infix operator" section pseudo-code (4th and 5th if statements).

Comment: Because `==` is a comparison operator, and those (`<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`) default to using numbers. On the other hand, `+` is the *string concatenation* operator. (That they are overloaded for other types is less than optimal, but yes that's "because JavaScript")

Comment: "*It is tough to remember*" - you shouldn't need to. Always compare values of the same type, and be explicit if you intend a coercion.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's just "because javascript". There are some good reasons that we might prefer one conversion over the other.  For `==`, converting both to numbers has nice properties. For example, comparing any two falsy values (except `NaN`) will return true, eg `"" == 0`. Similarly, in the case of `+`, since many strings aren't numeric, I'd rather have `"foo" + 1` be `"foo1"` than `NaN` (were we to convert both to numbers).

Comment: @CRice nice - you should write an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

why do you expect there is a one reason?
I believe there could be different aspects possible:

1. HTML data is not typed - it's all strings. The same is for HTTP. So there will be probably a lot of conversion required if you try to

   ```
   element.getAttribute('maxlength')> str.length
   ```

   So we better just deal with that fact string/number mix is not rear case(at least when EcmaScript started to be used)
2. trying to have the same approach for both "+" and ">" operators would generate more "WTF?". Say if we try to use "toString approach everywhere" then `2> '11'`. On the other side for "toNumber approach everywhere" we would see `NaN` in string concatenation result much more often that we would want.

Yes, it looks confusing. But it's more because of ambiguous goal of "+" as operator "add" and operation "concatenate" in the same time. Then you should used to operate this automatically.